# Id monodromy in hamiltonian dynamics

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations, hamiltonian-mechanics

In my problem I have non autonomous Hamiltonian which depends on 2 parameters (pretty close to oscillator Hamiltonian, $(a+b\cos t +1) p^2+(a+b\cos t-1)q^2$, $a,b$ - parameters). From numerical experiments and by some other ways its proven that for some values of parameters the monodromy matrix $M$ is identity - all solutions are periodic with period $2\pi$. Is there any kind of necessary condition for Hamiltonian so this could happen? For example its clear from numerical experiments that this happens only for integer values of $a$ what is pretty strange.

Comment: "It is clear from numerical experiments ...": are you talking about evidence from numerical experiments, or rather computational verification? -- These are two different things ... .

Comment: Have you tried to rewrite the equations of motion as Mathieu equations?